# How to center text in a schemabox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, packages

I would like the text in the nodes between the arrows to be centered rather than left aligned. Using `\centering` or `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` around the minipage or setting `text align=center` in the tikzpicture options doesn't help. I can't find further guidance in the [schemata](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/generic/schemata/schemata.pdf&ei=fIwlU5meJeqI0AG8noCYBQ&usg=AFQjCNEMJNClzc_7ipPpRIv7cTRjTcWqLQ&sig2=j_A98mByGyOhRT4IIueR_g&bvm=bv.62922401,d.dmQ) package. (I'm open to solutions that don't involve this package.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor, fontspec, schemata}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning, decorations.pathreplacing}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block}=[align=center]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw,-latex',ultra thick]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5em,auto,block]

    \node (prior-lit) {Prior literature};
    \node [below of=prior-lit] (aims-12) 
    {
        \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
            \let\SB\schemabox
            \schema{\SB{Aims 1 \& 2}}{\SB{\textbf{Identify} Risk and protective factors for \\ nonmedical poly- and monosubstance use\\  location, position in social network, age, gender}}
        \end{minipage}
       };
    \node [below of=aims-12, below=0em] (mock-intervention) 
    {
        \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
            \let\SB\schemabox
            \schema{\SB{Aim 3}}{\SB{\textbf{Simulate} responses of users with various \\ combinations  of risk and protective factors\\ to interventions on social networking sites}}
        \end{minipage}
       };


    \node [below of=mock-intervention] (real-intervention) {Real intervention};
    \node [below of=real-intervention] (outcomes) {Asses outcomes};

    \path[line] (prior-lit) -- (aims-12);
    \path[line] (aims-12) -- (mock-intervention); 
    \path[line, dashed] (mock-intervention) -- (real-intervention);
    \path[line, dashed] (real-intervention) -- (outcomes);

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=1em,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=-10] (5.5,-5) -- (5.5,0) node [right,black,midway,xshift=2em] {\textbf{Current grant}};

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=1em,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=-10] (5.5,-8) -- (5.5,-5.1) node [right,black,midway,xshift=2em] {\textbf{Future grants}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

The arrows are centered wrt the entire node. I used a `tabular` inside `\SB`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor, fontspec, schemata}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning, decorations.pathreplacing}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{block/.style={align=center},
         line/.style = {draw,-latex',ultra thick}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5em,auto,block]

    \node (prior-lit) {Prior literature};
    \node [below of=prior-lit] (aims-12)
    {
     %   \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
            \let\SB\schemabox
            \schema{\SB{Aims 1 \& 2}}{\SB{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Identify} Risk and protective factors for \\ nonmedical poly- and monosubstance use\\  location, position in social network, age, gender\end{tabular}}}
     %   \end{minipage}
       };
    \node [below of=aims-12, below=0em] (mock-intervention)
    {
       % \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
            \let\SB\schemabox
            \schema{\SB{Aim 3}}{\SB{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Simulate} responses of users with various \\ combinations  of risk and protective factors\\ to interventions on social networking sites\end{tabular}}}
    %    \end{minipage}
       };


    \node [below of=mock-intervention] (real-intervention) {Real intervention};
    \node [below of=real-intervention] (outcomes) {Asses outcomes};

    \path[line] (prior-lit) -- (aims-12);
    \path[line] (aims-12) -- (mock-intervention);
    \path[line, dashed] (mock-intervention) -- (real-intervention);
    \path[line, dashed] (real-intervention) -- (outcomes);

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=1em,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=-10] (5.5,-5) -- (5.5,0) node [right,black,midway,xshift=2em] {\textbf{Current grant}};

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=1em,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=-10] (5.5,-8) -- (5.5,-5.1) node [right,black,midway,xshift=2em] {\textbf{Future grants}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```